# In Solr Does Block Join Query Parsers lack regular expression feature?

Tags: solr, subquery

I need to have a query in which I need to choose only those parent docs none of whose children's field is having the specified value.
i.e. I need something like this:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/core1/select?q={!parent 
which=contentType:parent}childField:NOT value1
```

The problem is NOT operator is not being supported in the Block Join Query Parsers. Could anyone please suggest a way to workaround this problem?

For ex:

```
Suppose my docs are like this:
<doc>
    <field name="userid>1</field>
    <doc>
       <field name="address">city1</field>
    </doc>
    <doc>
       <field name="address">city2</field>
    </doc>
</doc>

<doc>
    <field name="userid>2</field>
    <doc>
       <field name="address">city2</field>
    </doc>
    <doc>
       <field name="address">city3</field>
    </doc>
</doc>
```

Now if I want a query to return me all the users not having any address related to city1 (i.e. only userid=2 should be in the result)and then if i query:

```
q={!parent which=userid:*}*:* -address:city1
```

This will return me two results i.e. userid=2 and userid=1 (as userid=1 is also having a child whose address is city2)  , desired output was userid=2 only.

Answer (score 0):

You use pure negative question, so you should add `*:*` to query start, also `childField:NOT value1` is incorrect, it means `(childField:NOT) AND (value1)`.

Correct query is

```
{!parent which=contentType:parent}*:* NOT childField:value1
```

Comment: didn't solve my problem.
added with example in detail in the problem statement

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't try to reproduce this issue right now, but are you sure your nested documents do not have uniqueKey set? Try to select from Solr with `q=*:*` and `fl=userId` and similar with `fl=field(userId)` and add results to question. Need to distinguish between two cases -- `userId:*` also matching nested documents OR wildcard is unsupported in `which` filter.